# How to build OpenSSH with no dependence on OpenSSL?

Tags: security, openssl, openssh

I am trying to build OpenSSH 7.3 without OpenSSL.

I ran `$ ./configure --without-openssl`.

And then running either `$ make  OPENSSL=no` or `$ make` give the following error:

```
In file included from ../entropy.h:30:0,
                 from ../includes.h:174,
                 from arc4random.c:27:
../buffer.h:50:29: fatal error: openssl/objects.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [arc4random.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory /local/store/openssh/openssh-7.3p1/openbsd-compat'
make: *** [openbsd-compat/libopenbsd-compat.a] Error 2
```

These includes are not properly wrapped with `#ifdef WITH_OPENSSL`, so are still reachable. What am I doing wrong?

How do I configure and build OpenSSH 7.3 without OpenSSL dependencies?

---

It seems that as of version 6.8 OpenSSH can be built without OpenSSL. From 6.8 release notes:

> - Support --without-openssl at configure time
>
>   Disables and removes dependency on OpenSSL. Many features,
>     including SSH protocol 1 are not supported and the set of crypto
>     options is greatly restricted. This will only work on systems
>     with native arc4random or /dev/urandom.

Also I found this message on OpenBSD CVS:

> CVSROOT:  /cvs
>
> Module name:  src
>
> Changes by:   markus@cvs.openbsd.org  2014/04/29 12:01:49
>
> Modified files:
>
> usr.bin/ssh    : Makefile.inc auth.c authfd.c authfile.c 
>                        bufaux.c cipher.c cipher.h hostfile.c kex.c 
>                        key.c mac.c monitor.c monitor_wrap.c 
>                        myproposal.h packet.c roaming_client.c 
>                        ssh-agent.c ssh-keygen.c ssh-keyscan.c 
>                        ssh-keysign.c ssh-pkcs11.h ssh.c sshconnect.c 
>                        sshconnect2.c sshd.c 
>       usr.bin/ssh/lib: Makefile 
>       usr.bin/ssh/ssh: Makefile 
>       usr.bin/ssh/sshd: Makefile
>
> Log message:
>   make compiling against OpenSSL optional (make OPENSSL=no);
>   reduces algorithms to curve25519, aes-ctr, chacha, ed25519;
>   allows us to explore further options; with and ok djm

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not trying to solve a programming problem.

Comment: I would appreciate if you would not,
I am trying to solve a compilation problem, putting the source code here would make the question to long

Comment: *"It seems that as of version 6.8 OpenSSH can be built without OpenSSL..."* - Does that hold for OpenSSH 7.x?

Comment: @jww Thank you for the edit. Yes it holds to 7.x according to the release notes and their public strategy. I can also see the flag `WITH_OPENSSL` in the source code wrapping a lot of code referring to OpenSSL, but apparently not all of it.

Comment: @Nimrod - File a bug report with OpenSSH. It won't get fixed unless they know about it.

Comment: @PeeHaa - I'm inclined to leave it open since Nimrod is trying to build things with Make and GCC. That's on-topic at Stack Overflow. He shows the results of running make, shows the error message from the compiler, and even analyzed some code. Its a welcomed distraction from all the off-topic crap we usually see under the OpenSSL tag. (Usually we see the questions on how to run an OpenSSL command, which have nothing to do with Stack Overflow; and are better suited for Super User or Unix & Linux Stack Exchange).

Comment: Hey it's your tag :-) Want me to retract my close vote? @jww

Answer (score 1):

I built **OpenSSH** **`7.7p1`** without `openssl` using:

`./configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc/ssh --with-privsep-path=/var/empty --libexecdir=/usr/lib/openssh --without-openssl`

I also used the `patch` from [Linux From Scratch](http://linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/openssh.html).